# Simplify multipolygon removing small gaps in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, simplify

Is there a way to simplify multipolygon by removing small gaps in PostGIS? Example:

Original:

[image]

Simplified:

[image]

It could also simplify the shape as `ST_Simplify` does but in addition it should remove small gaps between parts of the multipolygon.

Comment: Is that one multipolygon or two single parts?

Answer (score 7):

In the upcoming PostGIS 3.3 [`ST_ConcaveHull`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ConcaveHull.html) has been enhanced so that it respects boundaries when polygons are provided as input.  So for this case you should be able to simply create a concave hull around the input, with a suitable concaveness parameter.

The result should look something like this:
[image]

See also this [blog post](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2022/05/concave-hulls-of-polygons.html) on the **Concave Hull of Polygons** algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer once PostGIS 3.3 is released.

Comment: It's just been released: https://postgis.net/2022/08/27/postgis-3.3.0-released/

Comment: I've upgraded, but I am getting `ERROR:  lwgeom_concavehull: GEOS Error: IllegalStateException: Unable to find a convex corner`.

Comment: Add your geometry as WKT into your question so others can have a try with the same data.

Comment: There is a small known bug in the new algorithm, and unfortunately you've found it.  Posting your geometries as WKT will help to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

Join the layer to itself by distance, snap and [union](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301598/only-union-dissolve-intersecting-or-adjacent-features-to-speed-up-query):

```
WITH clusters 
  AS(select st_clusterdbscan(geom, 0, 2) over() cluster_id, geom 
  from 
    (select a.id as aid, case when a.geom is not null and b.geom is not null then st_snap(a.geom, b.geom, 500) else a.geom end as geom
    from public.polywithgaps a
    left join public.polywithgaps b
    on st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 500) --Change 500 to the distance you want to snap
    and a.id<b.id) sub)
    
select st_union(geom) geom from clusters
where cluster_id is not null
group by cluster_id
union
select geom from clusters where cluster_id is null
```

[image]

Comment: ++1 for sexy pgsql

Answer (score 1):

How about customizable buffering.

Configure and run this SQL script:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer((ST_Dump((ST_Union(ST_Buffer((geom),0.1, 'side=left join=mitre'))))).geom,-0.1,'side=left join=mitre') geom FROM <sourse_table>
```

You should get a result like in my image.

[image]

Fun original geospatial solutions...