# Unifying touching polygon within polygon geometry in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry, union

I have a polygon geometry with 100+ polygons originally converted from a raster table - see the below image

[image]

Zoomed view of one of the polygons

[image]

I would like to unify the touching polygons (i.e. sharing a common vertex or a part of the perimeter). I tried with `st_dump(st_union(...))` but it only unifies polygons which share a part of the perimeter and not a vertex. See below

[image]

I think I can do this by using `st_union` and `st_touches`. But I just don't know how to write the correct SQL with just one geometry as `st_tocuhes` requires two geometries. My below attempt creates one large multi-polygon with all the polygons which is not what I want

```sql
SELECT st_union(a.geom) AS geom
FROM orginal_geom a, original_geom b
WHERE st_touches(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend [this way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301598/only-union-dissolve-intersecting-or-adjacent-features-to-speed-up-query), it is very fast.

Each group of polygons is assigned the same id if they are 0 distance apart, and number at least 2, using [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html).

Single polygons will get NULL as cluster id.

```sql
with clusters as (
select st_clusterdbscan(geom, 0, 2) over() cluster_id, geom
from test.minigrid)

select st_union(geom) as geom
from clusters where cluster_id is not null
group by cluster_id

union

select geom from clusters where cluster_id is null
```

1.1 s. to dissolve 36 k squares:

[image]

Comment: ST_ClusterDBSCAN is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ST_ClusterIntersecting` or `ST_ClusterIntersectingWin` to do this.

Comment: ST_ClusterIntersectingWin(geom) returns an error 42883 function ST_ClusterIntersectingWin(geometry) does not exist, other function that do throw errors are: ST_ClusterWithinWin(), ST_CoverageInvalidEdges() ... these errors occur even though I use the example code from https://postgis.net/docs/